# choosing axis to flip a div using css

Tags: javascript, css

When setting -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) it always rotates with the axis being at the center of the div.  Is there a way to set it so that it flips from the far left or right edge of the div e.g. like how a door swings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-transform-origin